# Python parser, Str

Tags: python, string

I want to collect article title from HBR, but unfortunately I find a wrong header ,

```
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
```

what should I do ?

Code :

```
import requests

hbr_url = "https://hbr.org/service/components/list/latest/1/8?format=json&id=page.list.home"

hrb_header = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

}

hbr_data = requests.get(url=hbr_url , header = hrb_header)

hbr_json =hbr_data.json()

hrb_article =hbr_json['entry']


for title222 in hrb_article:
    hbr_title = hrb_article['title']
    print(hbr_title)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stanleydu/PycharmProjects/untitled19/hbbs.py", line 21, in <module>
    hbr_title = hrb_article['title']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Read the error message then look at the value of `hrb_article`  Try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `hbr_json['entry']` is a list of dictionaries, each of which has a `'title'` key. You are using the wrong variable inside your loop. You need:

```
hrb_article = hbr_json['entry']

for title222 in hrb_article:
    hbr_title = title222['title']  # <=== this is the corrected line
    print(hbr_title)
```

This gives:

```
Do You Have the Tools to Build a Great Employee Experience?
Remote Work Doesn’t Have to Mean All-Day Video Calls
4 Questions to Help Women Navigate the Second Half of Their Careers
The Case for Remote Work in Health Care
Creating More Resilient Supply Chains
Quantify Your Company’s Impact on People
A Better Approach to Fighting Chronic Diseases
How to Identify a Family-Friendly Employer
```

(Also in your call to `requests.get` it seems that you need `headers` rather than `header` for the name of the keyword argument. This is presumably just a mistake in the question, or it would have failed at that line.)

Comment: Man, you're the best, Thanks for the help, It works !!!